# C read linked list from file and write to another file

Tags: c, file, linked-list

I'm trying to make a program that would read a linked list and output all of the info that it has read. My problem is that I can't simply output. There is some problem that I can't find.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct sarasas
{
    char *reiksme;
    struct sarasas *kitas;
};



int main()
{
    struct sarasas *sarasasPtr, *pradz, *pab, *elem;

    pradz = NULL;
    pab = NULL;

    FILE *duomPtr;
    printf("Iveskite duomenu failo pavadinima: ");
    char failas[255];
    scanf("%s", failas);
    duomPtr = fopen(failas, "r");

    if(duomPtr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Toks duomenu failas neegzistuoja \n");
        exit(0);
    }

    int k = 0;
    char paimtaReiksme[255];

    while(fscanf(duomPtr, "%s", paimtaReiksme) != EOF)
    {
        if(k == 0)
        {
            sarasasPtr = (struct sarasas*)malloc (sizeof (struct sarasas));
            sarasasPtr->reiksme = paimtaReiksme;
            sarasasPtr->kitas = NULL;
            pradz = sarasasPtr;
            pab = sarasasPtr;
        }

        else
        {
            sarasasPtr = (struct sarasas*)malloc (sizeof (struct sarasas));
            sarasasPtr->reiksme = paimtaReiksme;
            sarasasPtr->kitas = NULL;
            pab->kitas = sarasasPtr;
            pab = sarasasPtr;
        }
        k++;
    }

    if(pradz == NULL &&  pab == NULL)
    {
        printf("Tuscia\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    FILE *rptr;
    printf("Iveskite rezultatu failo pavadinima: ");
    char failas2[255];
    scanf("%s", failas2);
    rptr = fopen(failas2, "w");

    while(sarasasPtr->kitas != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(rptr, "%s", sarasasPtr->reiksme);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem you are having ?

Comment: It got solved. Turns out loop was not ending. @Mhd.Tahawi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in your code.

```
while(sarasasPtr->kitas != NULL)
{
    fprintf(rptr, "%s", sarasasPtr->reiksme);
}
```

Here in the above `while` loop, **you are trying to print the same element over and over again** and thus you end up in an infinite loop.instead, you must change the pointer to next element after each and every iteration. You can try something like this:

```
while(sarasasPtr != NULL) //check whether pointer points to NULL
{
    fprintf(rptr, "%s", sarasasPtr->reiksme);
    sarasasPtr = sarasasPtr->kitas; //make pointer point to next element
}
```

additionally, you need not cast the the return value of `malloc` : **[Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/5281962)**(click)

Comment: I have found that this program only prints to the file one word. Maybe you know why is that so? @Cherubim ?

Comment: is it the last word that is only getting printed. the problem is that you are trying to point the same `char array[]` i.e, `paimtaReiksme` over and over again to the `sarasasPtr->reiksme`. try using `strcpy()` function

Comment: 1: include `string.h` header file | 2: use `strcpy(sarasasPtr->reiksme, paimtaReiksme);` instead of  `sarasasPtr->reiksme = paimtaReiksme;` everywhere

Comment: And don't forget to allocate memory for ` sarasPtr->reiksme` before using strcpy.... `saradPtr->reiksme = malloc(strlen(paimtaReiksme))`.. @AdomasArabella